# Date format validating

Tags: java, regex, validation, datetime-format

I have following method to check my date format validation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX");
    String dateString = df.format(new Date());
    Validator validator = new Validator();
    System.out.println(dateString+" = "+validator.isTimesStampValid(dateString));
    String given = "2016­-09-­28T14:50:31.456449+06:00";
    System.out.println(given+" = "+validator.isTimesStampValid(given));
}
```

I got results as following,

```
2016-11-21T12:18:18.000698+05:30 = false
2016-­09­-28T14:50:31.456449+06:00 = true
```

My date format validation regex is this, `^\d{4}­-\d{2}-­\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d+)?(\+|-­)\d{2}:\d{2}$`

I can't figure out why I'm getting two different results after validation. 
According to my understanding I should get same result for the values of `given` and `dateString`. Can any please explain why I'm getting this...

Comment: I would have expected *both* to return `false`, since your regex is missing the `-` between date parts. --- And what is `(\+|­)` supposed to match? A `+` or nothing? But what if time zone is `-03:00`?

Comment: Ahhh It looks like your regex has 'SOFT HYPHEN' (U+00AD) instead of normal `-` minus signs. Oops!! Voting to close as typo.

Comment: + to Andreas. Try using: \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d+)?(\+|\-)\d{2}:\d{2}

Comment: @Andreas, Sorry I missed it when I'm pasting regex here, now I have updated it. Also I can't change the regex it is a provided one.

Comment: @Andreas, thank u very much I haven't notice that hyphen thing no..

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention, that your regex:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d+)?(\+|-)\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

matches, according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/), both examples strings, provided, and few others which I produced.